# passing function as arguments from one class to another

Tags: java

I have a class called HelloWorld where I create an object of Class Test test = new Test();

then in the HelloWorld Class I have my main function and another:

```
public static int passMe(){
    System.out.println("running this function");
    return 1;
}
```

this is function im trying to pass. I pass it int test using the following:

```
test.getSomeFunction(new Callable<Integer>(){
              public Integer call(){
                  return passMe();
              }
          });
```

inside Test class I have:

```
    public void getSomeFunction(Callable<Integer> someFunction){
        System.out.println(someFunction);
    }
```

now all this works, but passMe() isn't being run, rather I don't know how to reference it.
if I print out someFunction, I get:

```
"HelloWorld$1@35a8767"
```

so my question is how do I go about running the function I got passed in, if I do someFunction() I get error message "he method someFunction() is undefined for the type Test"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    try {
        Integer result = callable.call();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
```

Exception have to be handled cause it is enforced by [Callable definition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html).

Note that you are not passing `passMe` function but callable object that can call it.

Comment: when I do .call() I get error: "Unhandled exception type Exception"